# Skip first 4 lines in txt file then split the rest and read it

Tags: c#, database, split

Here is my code, first I want to skip the first 4 letters and split the rest and read it to update my database based on txt file.

```
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    string lines = sr.ReadLine();

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] words = lines.Split(' ');
        string ReservationNumber = words[0];
        double deposit = Convert.ToDouble((words[1]));

        if (GetCustomer(ReservationNumber).Customer_Res_Number == ReservationNumber)
        {
            UpdateDeposit(ReservationNumber, deposit);
        }
        lines = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `File` class and *Linq* instead of `Stream`s and `Reader`s? In case of Linq, it's quite easy to skip `4` top file's lines - `Skip(4)`:

Skip `4` top *lines* (file's caption?):

```
// Data (lines) to process
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(filename)
  .Skip(4)                            // <- Skip first 4 lines (file's caption?)
  .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
  .Select(words => new {
     ReservationNumber = words[0],
     deposit = Convert.ToDouble(words[1]), 
    })
  .Where(rec => GetCustomer(rec.ReservationNumber).Customer_Res_Number ==
                rec.ReservationNumber);  

// Data Processing
foreach (var item in lines)
  UpdateDeposit(item.ReservationNumber, item.deposit);
```

In case you want to skip 1st `4` *characters* from the very 1st line (checksum or alike?):

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(filename)
  .Select((line, index) => index == 0 
     ? line.Substring(4) // <- Skip 4 first characters from the 1st line
     : line) 
  .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
...
```

Finally, if you want to skip `4` *characters* from *each* line:

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(filename)
  .Select(line => line.Substring(4)) // <- Skip 4 fisrt characters from each line
  .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...?

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    string newline = line.Substring(3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This one is to skip letters only not lines , but thank you